# How to make Spring Boot application on ECS start immediately with health check grace period = 0

Tags: amazon-web-services, spring-boot, amazon-ec2, amazon-ecs, amazon-elb

I am deploying one of ECS Spring Boot services from my workplace AWS account, in my own AWS account.
I am using identical settings for cluster, service, target group, autoscaling group. I recreated all components of this ECS service in my AWS account, and I don't think that I missed anything.

Both are running directly on EC2 instances through autoscaling groups (i.e. not Fargate).

The only difference is that the service in the workplace account has health check grace period = 0 in service settings, and the ECS task spins up very quickly, and is marked "healthy" in target group's dashboard, while in case of my account, this same app requires at least 300 seconds of grace period, otherwise the task is marked "unhealthy" and eventually terminates with message `STOPPED (Task failed ELB health checks in (target-group arn:...`, spinning up a new task, which terminates as well and so on.

Even with 300 seconds grace period, the task becomes "unhealthy" for a minute, and only then moves to "healthy" state.

Anyone knows why this happens? Why in case of my AWS account, my app needs 300 seconds of grace period to start in "healthy" state?

PS. In both autoscaling group settings, in "health checks" section, health check type is marked as "EC2" and health check grace period is zero (if that matters)

PS2. One more difference, the autoscaling group has `desired=3, min=1, max=10` in workplace account, and `desired=1, min=0, max=1` in my account

Comment: Can be a lot of things, your app is maybe running on way slower hardware and simply needs more time or you didn't configure the health checks or target groups  correctly or e.g. the ports aren't mapped correctly and health check can't get a 200 response result from your app or something like that. Would ssh into the ec2 instance and check what it is doing and whether it is responding as expected or not. Maybe it's running out of memory and fails? https://aws.amazon.com/de/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/troubleshoot-unhealthy-checks-ecs/

Comment: the hardware is absolutely identical, same AMI, same instance type (`t3.small`). it seems that the health check configuration was different - it was `unhealthy threshold = 2, healthy threshold = 5, timeout = 5` in case of my account, and `unhealthy threshold = 5, healthy threshold = 2, timeout = 10` in case of workplace account. amazing how this changed things so radically.

Comment: the "correct" config can fail 4 times waiting for 10 seconds each, that's enough for boot to start I guess, and answer on it's port (when the webserver has started). Your original config can fail only once and will try for just 5 seconds. Might make sense to add a grace period rather than hiding it in the health checks.